# Jasper reports - Changing date and number pattern as per user locale

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a crosstab where in I need to display dates and numbers as per the country's locale. I understand I need to use the text expression, but I am unable to figure how must I use with parameters. The locale comes in the form of 'en-IN'(for India), 'de-DE'(for Germany) and so on for all the countries. The date and number formats must change as per the locale of the person who as logged in

I have been able to obtain the user locale in the parameter. But, I do not know how to use it in the crosstab.

PFB the jrxml. I keep getting the error expression ID not found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2016-11-04T12:23:19 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="crosstabmeasure" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e47b3f7d-1e00-4702-a900-be50a229f085">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysql251"/>
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.time.*"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="set1" uuid="0271cb46-f184-47b2-8ab3-e6ee96ea33ef">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysql251"/>
        <parameter name="Locale" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["en-IN"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="UtcOffSet" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[330]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select * from internatioinlization]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="col3" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="col4" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Locale" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["en-IN"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="UtcOffSet" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["fi-FI"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from internatioinlization]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="col3" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="col4" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="211" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="211" uuid="6c5ccb8a-50fc-4158-b2ba-88d864aa1e43"/>
                <crosstabParameter name="Parameter1"/>
                <crosstabParameter name="Parameter2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
                <crosstabDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="set1" uuid="d255c9b9-fbb2-420a-8ef5-3236098654f1">
                            <datasetParameter name="Locale">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Locale}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="UtcOffSet">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UtcOffSet}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                </crosstabDataset>
                <rowGroup name="col11" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="86c09a7f-46b5-4d2f-ba87-715f99d832a8"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col11}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="94fca0ea-1572-4d42-85d9-b06f92c73b6e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col11]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="col41" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20" uuid="137ef406-6a2e-4629-9d38-4858c4a5ae2c">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col41}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="5c71211d-f1db-4911-8923-2bdb208ddb99"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col41]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="col2_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="col3_MEASURE1" class="java.util.Date">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="861d0d3a-d774-4b0c-ae7d-ace315bf305c"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="163ed502-e753-444a-942d-832d84da0a5f">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1} != null ? DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale($P{Parameter1}.split("-")[0], $P{Parameter1}.split("-")[1])).format(DateUtils.addMinutes($V{col3_MEASURE1},$P{Parameter2})) : null]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="col41">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2576b9e2-3bba-40e3-aa15-5f4f0aada549"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a111181f-b60f-4afd-8292-9e260c1b9ce2"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9adf6c9c-acee-4673-8b70-a376e7d1cbb4"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9baedeed-4770-4153-b639-afc0965e9467"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11" columnTotalGroup="col41">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a2805e0a-080d-42be-ad86-a7e8e666f571"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col2_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="c485f69d-91e1-4b19-a8ab-bdbfa3cafcc6"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col3_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Thanks in advance
 Rathi

Comment: Hi All, Any ideas on solving the problem above?

Answer (score 0):

Mh, that's actually a weird problem, because usually the date and number formats are done by the Java engine.

You could create a resource bundle and add `pattern.date = DD.MM.YYYY` to it.
In the date textfield just change the pattern expression to `$R{pattern.date}` and you are ready to go.